# How to return Scikit-image Segmentation in 3D array?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, gdal, scikit-image

I have a four band raster images (which is a 3D array) and I would like to segment the image band by band. The shape of this raster (after converted into a 3D array) is `(12200, 7200, 4)`.

I have tried using scikit-image:

```
skimage.segmentation.slic(image[, …])
```

and

```
skimage.segmentation.quickshift(image[, …])
```

and the result is only a 2D array (= 1 band raster), with the shape of (12200, 7200).

The command seemed to have flatten the image and I cannot find anything in their documentation regarding the matter.

Here is what I've tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic, quickshift
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float

# The input 4-band TSX image
image = r'raw_img/09K0153_20140501T084638_TSX.tif'

#convert image to Np array
img = io.imread(image, as_gray=False, plugin="gdal")

# Run the quick shift segmentation
segments = quickshift(img, kernel_size=3, convert2lab=False, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)
```

How do I produce 3D segmentation result (that means, input: 3D array, output: 3D array) using Scikit-image, instead of 2D? Or is there another library that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

Indeed, the `quickshift` algorithm only returns a single (x, y) mask. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/segmentation/_quickshift_cy.pyx). If you give more than one channel to the algorithm, it will take all of the channels into account to compute the segmentation mask.

If you want to apply the algorithm independently to each channel, you have to do it iteratively, for instance with the following code

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic, quickshift
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float

# The input 4-band TSX image
image = r'raw_img/09K0153_20140501T084638_TSX.tif'

#convert image to Np array
img = io.imread(image, as_gray=False, plugin="gdal")

# Instantiate a segments array of same shape than image
segments = np.zeros(img.shape)
Nc = img.shape[-1] # number of channels

# Run the quick shift segmentation for each channel
for c in range(Nc):
    segments[:,:,c] = quickshift(img[:,:,c], kernel_size=3, convert2lab=False, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you @Christian! That helps. I've just found out that I can use slic segmentation with multichannel=False argument as well.

Comment: You're welcome! Cool then, just know that `quickshift` and `slic` are different algorithms (hence depends on what you are trying to do...).
A side note, if you consider that your question has been answered, you should [mark it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you think your new way to solve your problem with `slic` is better/simpler, you can also answer your own question and mark this as the better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I produce 3D segmentation result (that means, input: 3D array,
>   output: 3D array) using Scikit-image, instead of 2D?

Let's look at what it really means to have a 3D segmentation result as a 3D array. Let's consider a 3 channel image shown below. The segmentation we are interested in is shown in the blue dotted line.

[image]

Assume for now that there is some algorithm that will segment the blue dotted segment for us. But then how to represent the blue dotted segment?
 If it was a square of a rectangle shape we could have represented the segment in a 3D numpy array (3D slice of the original image). But if the image is arbitary shape then how do we do it? 
Segmentation information is captured using a mask. A mask 2D array corresponding to the size of the image is created. Let's assume we have only one segment in our image. In such a case all the pixels inside the segment of the image are marked as 1 in the corresponding mask image. This is a boolean mask (1 segment). If there are multiple segments then pixels in each segment as a unique number.

This is the reason you see that the result of the `quickshift` is a 2D array with the same dimension of the image. The result is the mask, the locations in the mask having the same values correspond to a segment which will represent a slice (which will be the same for all the channels). However, you will not be able to represent the slice using a numpy array if it of arbitary shape.

Just to add it is a bad idea to run `quickshift` of one channel at a time because it uses 5D space consisting of color information and image location 2 for segmentation. Using it on 1 channel at a time will give you bad segmentation results.